# Scatter plot size not changing as expected matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

I am trying to change the size of my scatter plot in Jupyter but it is acting all funky.  The plot isn't resizing as expected.

```
x1 = df['budget_adj']
y1 = df['vote_average']
plt.title('Average Vote vs. Adjusted Budget')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20,10]
plt.scatter(x1,y1,s=.5)
plt.show()
```

When I change the values inside of plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20,10] to [10,5], for example, the width and height double in size.  If I change the values to [20,1], the chart resizes to the same size as [10,5].  Any idea what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your observations are misled because you always change the size of *the next* figure. You need to put `plt.rcParams...` before creating the figure, i.e. at least before `plt.title`.

Comment: Hey, this is perfect thanks so much.  I am new to this and had no idea! You have just cured a massive headache of mine!